# Como criar uma conexão com o banco de dados H2 utilizando Spring Data?

Tags: banco-de-dados, spring-data

Jogaram no meu colo um projeto que será feito com Spring Framework e querem que a persistência de dados seja feita com Spring Data.

Nunca trabalhei com nenhum dos dois e estou tendo uma profunda dificuldade em gerar a persistência.

Já tentei este guia, mas não funciona: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Como posso fazer corretamente a configuração do Spring Data utilizando o banco H2?

Em application.properties ficou assim:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/nomedobanco
spring.datasource.username=login
spring.datasource.password=senha
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

No Pom, estou usando esses pacotes para o jpa e SpringData:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

E o erro que Recebo é esse:

> 2015-04-13 13:26:31.721  INFO 5068 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core
>   {4.3.8.Final} 2015-04-13 13:26:31.723  INFO 5068 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found 2015-04-13 13:26:31.725  INFO 5068 ---
>   [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            :
>   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist 2015-04-13 13:26:31.893 
>   INFO 5068 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final} 2015-04-13
>   13:26:31.989  INFO 5068 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 2015-04-13 13:26:32.051  INFO 5068 ---
>   [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    :
>   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 2015-04-13 13:26:32.253 
>   INFO 5068 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl
>   schema export 2015-04-13 13:26:32.256  INFO 5068 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export
>   complete 2015-04-13 13:26:33.261  WARN 5068 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not an managed type: class MarlinAlarme.Objects.User  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
>     at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)     at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not an managed type: class MarlinAlarme.Objects.User  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 52 common frames omitted

Comment: Paulo, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Editei sua pergunta para tentar adequá-la mais ao formato de perguntas e respostas do site. Entretanto, fique à vontade para editá-la novamente se achar pode pode melhorar ou acrescentar mais informações. Além disso, o SO funciona melhor com perguntas mais específicas. Tutoriais não são por si só a resposta para um problema. Poderia, por favor, postar sua configuração atual do Spring Data? Quais erros estão ocorrendo?

Comment: Obrigado, Atualizei o Post com os dados que tenho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro original não é exatamente sua configuração. Veja abaixo:

> Not an managed type: class MarlinAlarme.Objects.User

Isso quer dizer que sua classe `User` não é uma entidade JPA. De alguma forma você deve estar tentando usar isso como uma entidade.

Enfim, pelo menos até agora parece não haver nenhum problema de configuração. Verifique apenas essa questão da classe `User` não ser uma entidade JPA.

Comment: Andei lendo e vi que eu tenho que declarar essa classe como entidade em algum lugar, mas não encontro como criar um bean ou um xml. :(

Comment: Anote a classe com `@Entity` e veja se resolve. Caso contrário, você vai precisar configurar corretamente a anotação `@JpaRepositories` na sua configuração.

Comment: Já esta @entity na classe. rsrsrsrs. Vou dar uma olhada aqui em como eu configuro isso.

Answer (score 0):

Uma certa vez tive um problema parecido ao utilizar o H2 e descobri que era um erro meu, pois não havia colocado um atributo na minha classe objeto... o **"id"** com suas devidas anotações.

```
@Entity
class Product {

@Id // Eu havia esquecido de colocar o atributo "id" com essas duas anotações
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name='LOJA')
String loja
@Column(name='CODIGO')
String codigo
@Column(name='DESCRICAO')
String descricao
}
```

Comment: Especifique melhor a solução, a resposta está muito genérica.   *etc* não é muito bem vindo numa resposta, coloque mais exemplos práticos. Vlw.